# revisionHistory is showing for some models but not others

Tags: laravel, revisionable

I checked the revisions table in the database and their are revision records for the record I'm trying to show the history for.

$record->revisionHistory returns an empty array though.

The same code for other models works fine, it is really strange.

This model code works:

```
namespace App\Models\Slack;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes as SoftDeletes;

class Channel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;

    protected $revisionEnabled = true;
    protected $revisionCleanup = true;
    protected $historyLimit = 10;
    protected $revisionCreationsEnabled = true;
```

This controller code for the above model works:

```
$channel = Channel::find($id);
return $channel->revisionHistory;
```

This model code doesn't work (but there are records in the database):

```
namespace App\Models\Organization;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes as SoftDeletes;

class Organization extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;

    protected $revisionEnabled = true;
    protected $revisionCleanup = true;
    protected $historyLimit = 10;
    protected $revisionCreationsEnabled = true;
```

This controller code for the model above display an empty array ([]):

```
$organization = Organization::find($id);
return $organization->revisionHistory;
```

Comment: In your first example, both lines use `$channel`. In your second, the first line uses `$organization` and the second uses `$organization_history`. Try `$organization->revisionHistory`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that but that is a typo on my end when I was putting this example. It still doesn't work when I make that change.

Comment: Try doing `$organization->revisionHistory()->toSql()` and see what SQL is generated. Then try running the query yourself directly against SQL.

Comment: @ceejayoz I ran that and it did display some SQL, the SQL was the same for both the working model and the model that isn't working. select * from "revisions" where "revisions"."revisionable_id" = ? and "revisions"."revisionable_id" is not null and "revisions"."revisionable_type" = ? Is there a way to see what parameters are being passed in? I manually put them and it did return a record: select * from "revisions" where "revisions"."revisionable_id" = 1 and "revisions"."revisionable_id" is not null and "revisions"."revisionable_type" = 'App\Models\Organization\Organization';

Comment: I believe `$organization->revisionHistory()->getBindings()` gives you the values being passed to `?`.

Comment: @ceejayoz you are correct, thank you very much. It looks like the morphMap that I have setup in my boot method under the AppServiceProvider class is causing just organization to be passed through. Any suggestions on how to make this work with revisionable?

Answer (score 0):

I have a morphMap setup in my AppServiceProvider boot method that is firing when revisionable calls for the record so this is why nothing is being returned. I am going to close this and open a new question that is more relevant.